# Is there a command that will tell me if there is no screen activity?

Tags: focus

**Summary:**

Is there a command which will tell me if there is any screen activity
currently taking place on my Debian system?

**Full Details:**

Towards the end of every boot, I run the Kate text editor from a script in
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/.  I do this to display the contents of a file* that has
reminders in for me to see (*using Kate).

I want the Kate window to be the FOCUSED window when the boot finishes and all
screen activity has stopped. But at that point, I'm finding that SOMETIMES the
Kate window is UNFOCUSED, even though there are no other windows open.

So in my script that launches Kate, I'd like to run a command that checks for
when there is NO screen activity, so that I can launch Kate, knowing that it
will be the focused window.

I realise that I could use a startup script that runs later than those in
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/. But I WOULD like to know if there is a command that tells
you if there is any screen activity taking place.

Comment: What do you mean by “screen activity”? I can't think of a definition that would relate to your problem. If some other window gets the focus after Kate starts, that doesn't mean there was any activity at the time Kate started, it means there was activity later, so how would checking for “activity” at the time of launching Kate help?

Comment: @Gilles: Towards the end of the boot, there are 6 main things that happen, but the order of them sometimes varies from that shown below: a) The Linux splash screen is displayed. b) IF the VGA socket has a plug in it, the screen resolution is changed from 16:9 to 4:3. c) The Kate window is displayed. d) The blue Desktop background is displayed. e) The Desktop icons are displayed. f) The LXDE desktop panel (along bottom) is displayed.

Comment: @Gilles So I'd like to have a command that can determine when all the above screen activity has finished BEFORE I run Kate, so that Kate is the focused window. But in the future, I may add some other action that alters the appearance of the screen or Desktop in some way, perhaps something as simple as displaying another application window. Therefore it would be useful to have a command that can determine if there is no such screen activity going off. And then I can run Kate, so that it is the focused window, or run xdotool to re-focus the Kate window.

Comment: @user216919 You have various programs that, at some point, decide to display some windows. Until they do act on the windows, there is no “screen activity”, just some program starting up. It's impossible to predict whether a program is going to act on the screen later.